# Running 2 unique list on a function with 2 variables in R

Tags: r, lapply

Right now i am pulling out data from different CSV named `test1_october`, `test2_october`... from file `October` on my desktop. What my list does (I think) is compiles the name of all the tests (`test1_october`, `test2_october`, `test3_october`) and runs them on the function, and then binds all the data together.

```
compilation_file <- c("test1_october", "test2_october","test3_october")

list_compilation <- vector("list", length(compilation_file))

names(list_compilation) <- compilation_file

tests<- lapply(compilation_file, function(test_name) {

Reponses<-read.csv(paste("/Users/Desktop/October/response/",test_name,".csv", sep = ""))
.
.
.
 test_combined<-cbind()

  return(test_combined)
})

test_combined<-do.call(rbind,tests)
```

However, i want to try further this script to pull data from more than 1 file, so making the filename a variable in the function. For example, January, February... October, November, December

How do i add this second variable on the function and run this variable on another list, it will scan different folders and pull out the respective UNIQUE CSV.

```
compilation_file <- c("test1_october", "test2_october","test3_october","test4_november","test5_december")

compilation_folder <- c("january", "february", "october","november","december")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but i'll give it a try.

But if you try to give the filename as a parameter to your function you will just have to do something like this for your compilation_file :

```
    lfilename = toLower(filename)
    compilation_file_temp <- c("test1_"+lfilename, "test2_"+lfilename,"test3_"+lfilename)

    compilation_file <- c(compilation_file,compilation_file_temp)
```

This would be inside a loop that loops over the file names that you have inside a vector for example.

I'm not sure that this is what you want.

Comment: Hi Zakaria, thats a great addition but unfortunately my priority is open different folders according to the list and search for filename according to the list.

For example,Open foldernames: January February,... December
Look for individual file unique in each folder

Comment: If you want to open multiple csv files check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r